# String does not act as valid json object when returned from Controller

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm trying to read a string from a json response however I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position

I have a controller which returns a guid as a string from the DB

```
[HttpPost("TransactionOrderId/{id}")]
public async Task<string> TransactionOrderId(int id)
{
    return await this._service.GetTransactionOrderId(id);
}
```

In my Angular 2 application I'm subscribing to my provider which has trouble parsing my response from my server.

```
this.meetingsProvider.getTransactionOrderId(this.meetingId).subscribe((transactionId: string) => {
    this.transactionOrderId = transactionId;
});
```

And My Provider code looks like so:

```
getTransactionOrderId(meetingId: number): Observable<string> {

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return  this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/${this.route}/transactionOrderId/${meetingId}`, null, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => <string>res.json());
}
```

My Server Responds with the proper transaction order id the response looks like so:

```
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 2
url: "http://localhost/api/meetings/transactionOrderId/4"
_body: "0c290d50-8d72-4128-87dd-eca8b58db3fe"
```

I have other api calls using the same code that return bool which return fine, but when I try to return string I get a parsing error why?

Comment: Yeah sorry, as has been said, it's not a valid json what the server is returning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a valid JSON object, that's why you get that error.  A JSON object starts with `{` and ends with `}`.

If you want to be able to JSON-deserialize that, use:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> TransactionOrderId(int id)
{
    return Json(await this._service.GetTransactionOrderId(id));
}
```

Note that if you return anything that is not a string, ASP.NET Core should JSON-serialize it (that's the default serializer anyway).

Comment: Hmm, I was testing a few things before.  I didn't realize only double quotes count as valid json for a string.   I want to do this generically for all Tasks of string but thats outside the scope of this question.  Thanks for the response